# CORS - Laravel on UBuntu 18.04 Via AJAX

Tags: php, laravel, cors

I have two local domains (domainone.io and domaintwo.io ) and I would like to allow CORS between both.

On the server I did allow it by :

```
server {
    listen    80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domainone.io;
    root /media/....../domain1/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'domaintwo.io';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'Content-Type';
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

And on the second domain :

```
server {
    listen    80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domaintwo.io;
    root /media/....../domain2/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'domainone.io';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'Content-Type';
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

ISSUE:

When I make an ajax call from either domain, I still get  the CORS not enabled error message, specifically:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://domainone.io/test. (Reason: CORS
>   header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

My JS is something like:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
  var someX = "lol";
  var token  = $('[name="csrf-token"]').prop("content");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://domaintwo.io/test',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {_token: token, test:someX },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function() {

    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: idk if this will help but you have 2 "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" the second one need to be "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"

Comment: Even after  fixing that I get the same errors

Comment: Debug your request using the developer tools of the browser, look at the network tab and see if CORS settings you applied actually reflected.

Comment: Also, include crossDomain: true, in your jQuery

Comment: @et3rnal no, don't do that. It does **not** do what you think it does

Comment: @codiiv I suggest you read this ~ https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html. Also, your allowed origins should include the HTTP scheme, ie `http://domainone.io`

Answer (score 1):

I think installing [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) will solve your problem